# Symfony did not create model

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I am going through symfony book and trying to do jobeet project(I use propel).. so here what book says

> The ORM also generates PHP classes that map table records to objects:
>   **$ php symfony propel:build --model**
>   The propel:build --model task generates PHP files in the lib/model/ directory that
>   can be used to interact with the database.

I run that command and when i go to lib/ direcotry , there is no model folder :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write:

```
$ php symfony propel:build-model
```

Comment: http://goo.gl/5LlOM This is what I get in console... but sill there is no lib/model

Comment: Currently I'm working on windows and maybe I misunderstood the path... your path is the project one?

Comment: yes..it is directory when I type ls -lah i get all folders like data,lib,web....:)

Comment: bosnian@ubuntu:~/dev/organization1/project1/htdocs/web$
well i have all premissions..I use ubuntu server on vm :)

Comment: Hoping this not becames a puzzle... did you get .sql file with propel:build-sql

Comment: Try to use `$ php symfony -t propel:build-model` to show a verbouse output... I hope in this way you can find the problem

Comment: I run your command ... no errors.. after that i run without -t and get this http://goo.gl/jMlUm

Comment: hehe.. in previous tasks I made typing error.. xD that is becouse I <3 GIT :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo ./symfony project:permissions
./symfony project:cc
./symfony propel:build-all-load // this will write to your db as well
```

otherwise please consider pasting the output of propel:build-model and your symphony version :)